# Unable to setup database for wordpress in MariaDB

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I've been let down by a web developer who also hosts my site for me. Two years after starting my new site he's gone totally AWOL and refuses to pick up the phone to me, or anyone else for that matter.

I do have access to my control panel though, and I've created a wordpress based site I'm happy with so I'd like to get that online now.

However, the control panel is not what I'm used to. It uses MariaDB which I've never heard of. I've created a new database but I'm unable to view or change user priviledges  which is where I'm stuck.

Would anyone be able to help me get through this step and on my way to success?!? I'm not a noob to wordpress but the DB side of things isn't something I'm hugely familiar with, but I can follow instructions!

If I've missed any crucial information please let me know!

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL so it's pretty similar. You should be able to upload your database using PHPMyAdmin or whatever it is your control panel provides.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have made the database and also uploaded wordpress to a folder using FTP but when I go to the URL where I should be seeing the wordpress setup dialogue I'm geting a 403 forbidden message.

Comment: When I log into the control panel and click 'manage' for the database I've created there's a red warning message saying 'No Privileges' and when I click on user accounts I get the message 'Not enough privilege to view users.'

Comment: You may want to reach out to your hosting provider so they can help you with the database issue. As for the Forbidden message, hard to say what's going on without more details. Your hosting provider _may_ also be able to help with this but IMO it might be a good idea to hire a developer and have them look into this for you.